# automatically add git version (git describe) to C code string in Eclipse (STM32CubeIDE)

Tags: c, git, eclipse, makefile, stm32cubeide

How do I automatically add git version (git describe) to C code string in Eclipse (STM32CubeIDE)?

This is pretty straightforward when using custom makefiles:

```
exe:
    @touch ./myMainProgram.c
    @echo -n "#define GIT_VERSION  \""                  >  ./git_ver.h
    @echo -n `git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always` >> ./git_ver.h
    @echo "\""                                          >> ./git_ver.h
```

And in your C code, you include `git_ver.h` and print the version with something like `printf("Version [%s]\n", GIT_VERSION);`

WARNING:  Do not use git to check in and track `git_ver.h` because any time it changes, `git describe` will identify your release as "dirty".

But in Eclipse (STM32CubeIDE) I can't edit the makefile directly because it is auto-generated.  How do I accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the auto-generated `makefile`, you'll notice this section:

```
-include ../makefile.defs
```

You can create your own `makefile.defs` file and add the following

```
OBJS += doGitVersion

doGitVersion:
    @touch ./myMainProgram.c
    @echo -n "#define GIT_VERSION  \""                  >  ./git_ver.h
    @echo -n `git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always` >> ./git_ver.h
    @echo "\""                                          >> ./git_ver.h
```

By the way, the `@touch` is there to force a re-compile of `myMainProgram.c` (and thereby refreshing the value of `GIT_VERSION` in the compiled binary).  If you don't do this, often build systems will not actually re-compile code if nothing has changed.

A typical situation is that you do a git commit, re-build, and re-test.  Everything looks good, so you tag the release with `v1.0.2` and re-build.  If you don't have the `@touch` line, since the build system detects that nothing has changed, it won't actually re-compile anything and you might have something like `v1.0.1-1-gfe093cd` left in the compiled binary for the value of `GIT_VERSION`.

By using the `@touch` line, you'll assure that `myMainProgram.c` gets re-compiled and `GIT_VERSION` reflects exactly what `git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always` returns.